# Extending the type definition of a native object with polyfills

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I have extended the native Set object with the following method:

```
Set.prototype.difference = function(setB) {
    var difference = new Set(this);
    for (var elem of setB) {
        difference.delete(elem);
    }
    return difference;
}
```

This code isn't type checked by flow because it's in a file I haven't enabled it yet. But if I decide to do so it'll throw a `difference property not found in Set` error. Using the difference method also throws an error.

I have tried writing the following code:

```
type ExtendedSet = Set & { difference: ExtendedSet => ExtendedSet }
const A: ExtendedSet = new Set(arrayA)
const B: ExtendedSet = new Set(arrayB)
const C = A.difference(B)
```

Comment: You'd be _much_ better off making this a utility function. Adding things to a prototype that you don't own is extremely bad form. It also makes the type annotations work properly.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've done exactly that, works fine now. I don't see why it's bad form. MDN has prototype extension in their own docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Generally it's bad to mutate globals, since you never know what other code on the page might be relying on `Set` objects. Consider it the other way, what if some third-party library on the page was setting this? Then if your code did it too, it might break unless they had exactly the same arguments and same behavior defined. Assigning to the prototype like that also means you're creating an enumerable property, where all the other methods on the prototype are non-enumerable.

Comment: It also means you no longer know where a method is coming from. Say you want to refactor later to split the code that uses `.difference` into a separate module, will you remember that it isn't standard? Someone without deep knowledge of your code might easily miss that, meaning you're refactored code without piece that defined `difference` wouldn't work and you might not realize.

Comment: @loganfsmyth all fair points!